# Is IoT SE able to handle Technical Questions with Accuracy?

Tags: discussion

Is IoT SE able to handle Technical Questions with Accuracy?

Or is there simply too small a pool of people who can tell workable ideas from unworkable ones which are obviously unbacked by any subject knowledge or practical experience?

There unfortunately seem to be a steady stream of both incomplete questions which lack critical detail required to make them answerable.

And worse **grossly ignorant** replies proposing entirely unworkable ideas, which nonetheless get upvotes from those who also lack the subject knowledge to understand why they cannot work.

The contrast with the successful *fact-based* SE sites like Stackoverflow and Electronics Stack Exchange is hard to ignore.  Had these problem questions or answers been posted on an SE site with real *community of technical knowledge* then as we see daily on those sites:

- the questions missing key information would have been quickly closed, and re-opened only if/when the missing details required to make them answerable were provided in an edit
- unworkable, erroneous, misleading answers would be rapidly downvoted and quickly reach the negative threshold where they are removed from general view
- the wealth of community knowledge would provide accurate, practical answers to the questions which are complete enough to be answerable

Is IoT Stack Exchange going to be a place where properly stated technical question can receive technically practical answers?

Or is it going to be a place where poor questions receive poor, misleading answers?

If this is not a site where technical questions can receive accurate answers *validated by a community of users having actual topic knowledge*, then it would seem that someone with an issue they need to *actually solve* must post it on Electronics Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow, *even* if the *issue being asked about* is squarely within the realm of IoT.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that the likes of SO, SU and Electronics receive a similar proportion of erroneous or misleading answers as this site.

On all sites, such answers are downvoted and/or eventually deleted - that is the SE way.

The difference here is simply the number of visitors.  On the large sites, really bad answers disappear quite quickly.  Here, good answers receive fewer upvotes and bad answers fewer downvotes simply because fewer people see them.  Therefore, the differentiation between answers is smaller.  The system here is working.  The IoT site is not the only small beta within the StackExchange network that has this issue.

The thing to do is to keep voting.  The more visitors this site gets, the more votes will be placed and the quicker bad answers will sink to the bottom of the list.

IoT *is* fact-based and is successful - just smaller.  Keep on visiting and voting and the site will grow and become more successful.